# Why is removing an element from the start of an ArrayList slower than that from its end?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have been told that

> When we create an ArrayList, internally an Array of a specific size
>   (say 50) is created. When the items being added to the list exceeds
>   50, a new Array of a bigger size (say 100) is created internally, and
>   they items of the original Array are copied to this new Array.

Then I was told that

> When we remove an item from the end of the list, all that is done
>   internally is decrementing the size of the list internally.But
>   removing an element which is located somewhere at the start of the
>   ArrayList is VERY slow, because it will have to copy all the
>   subsequent items one step back, so it is very slow.

But as it is implied in the first quote that an ArrayList is internally represented by an Array, and since you can't change the size of an array once it is allocated; you have to create a new Array.

- This means that when an element is removed at the end of the ArrayList, a new array is
  created *internally*, whose size is *one less than the size of the original
  array*, and all elements of first array are copied to the new one.
- When an element is removed from the start of the ArrayList, a new
  array is created *internally* whose size is one less than the size of
  the original array, and all elements of the first array are copied to
  the new one, such that the index position of each *subsequent* element in the new
  array is one less than that index position of this element in the
  previous/original array.

**Is my concept correct?**

**If yes, then I don't see why should the time/number-of-steps required to remove an element from the start of an arraylist be drastically slower than that when the element is removed from the end of the array.**

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct. A new array is only created when there is not enough space in the array to contain all the elements.

An ArrayList containing 4 elements (a, b, c, d) is represented as the following:

```
array: [a, b, c, d, null, null, null, null, null, null]
size: 4
```

Removing the last element from the list changes its content to

```
array: [a, b, c, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
size: 3
```

All the list has to do is decrement the size integer, and set the 4th element to null.

Removing the first element changes its content to

```
array: [b, c, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
size: 2
```

The list must decrement the size, copy a to the first index, copy b to the second index, set the third index to null. That's more work, especially if the list is much longer.

Comment: Thank you. In the second pseudocode/whatever-it-is-called, `3` is the size of the `ArrayList` right, but the size of the `Array` which is internally representing the `ArrayList` is still `4`, right?

Comment: No. As you can see, the array length is 10. The 6 last elements are null (in the first snippet). The length stays 10 until a 11th element is added to the list. Then only, a new array is created, of length 20, and all the elements are copied from the first array to the new one.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I was mistaken. What I should have said was that the size of that `Array` remains 10 throughout, right. Thank you. I am clear about it now.

Comment: Note that the actual initial length might be different from 10, and the new length might be other than 2 times the initial length. This is just an example illustrating the mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

There is no creation of a new array when you delete an element from the end, neither when you delete an element from the beginning, but the elements need to be moved a lot more if its the last element than if its the first one, there is your time difference.